# PlacesService class nearbySearch() method does not return some of the places

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have tried to search for places around my area without setting the name or keyword properties using `nearbySearch()` method, I got 20 places as result, below is some of them:

1. Name: Subway
2. Name: Saj 2 Go
3. Name: Alkabab Al Afghani
4. Name: Pizza di pisa
5. Name: Chicken Tikka Inn
6. Name: Al Mukhtar Chicken Restaurant
7. Name: **Le Jardin**
8. Name: Flavours
9. Name: 阿富汗餐厅
10. Name: Chutney Mary Restaurant Dubai
11. Name: Mandi Plov Restaurant
12. Name: Bilal afghan Restaurant
13. Name: **Papa John's** ...etc

Now I have picked one of the places name above (Le Jardin or Papa John's) and I have modified my search criteria to include it in the name property but I keep on getting ZERO_RESULTS, the place shows in the result when I don't specify the name or keyword property, but it does not when I do, could someone help me understand? :)

note: it works for other places in the list like (Subway, Saj 2 Go).

Below is the code I am using:

```
var map;
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var contentHTML = "";
function initMap() {
  var myLocation = {lat: 25.168062, lng: 55.403393};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: myLocation,
     zoom: 15
  });

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch({
    location: myLocation,
    radius: 500,
    name: "Le Jardin",  // this won't work, try removing name property and the place will show in the result
    type: ['restaurant']
}, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {          
            contentHTML += "Name: " + results[i].name + "<br>";
        }
    content.innerHTML = contentHTML;
    console.log(results.length);
    }else{
        console.error(status);
    }//end of if() 
}//end of callback()
}//end of initMap()
```

Comment: The results I get for your example (when `name` is commented out) do not include "Le Jardin".

Comment: Strange! how about "Papa John's"?

Comment: And when you include it in the name property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you people, but I have figured it out, I tried to comment out the type property and it worked, I tried as well to write Restaurant with capital R, and it worked too, I am not sure why although the google maps API documentation listed restaurant with small letter r.
:)